# INFO: HHH000318: Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath, despite file being present

Tags: hibernate, jpa, netbeans

Here is how my project structure looks:

[image]

When I right-click project and add a persistence unit, the percistence.xml is added in "Configuration Files". I Copied percistence.xml after getting this exception to "Web Pages/META-INF" and the same exception was thrown. I tried deleting percistence.xml from "Configuration Files" and the same exception was thrown also
This is what the properties in my percistence.xml looks like:

```
<persistence-unit name="PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://ramysazure.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName=SocialDB"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="HI1033@ramysazure"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="******"/>
  <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `META-INF` directory to your `Source Packages` or even `resources`. You will typically have the structure of `src/main/java` for your sources, and the resources will be in `src/main/resources`. That directory is for files that will be copied to the build destination and not processed.

Keep the `WEB-INF` where it is, though.

Comment: That fixed it thanks. Any Idea why Netbeans creates the project with wrong structure?

Comment: The `META-INF` in the web pages serves a different purpose. As for why, I'd say it was written by someone who hasn't tried actually deploying the default template project.